# aggregating rows by id into multiple columns where number of rows per id varies (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape, plyr

My question got shut down due to being a duplicate since i did not explain myself well. Here in is the problem which has since thwarted my use of gather-unite-spread of dplyr. Usually this is a simple task but there are a few issues that make this somewhat difficult to implement with this dataset.

I have the following data set

```
ID   V.1  V.2  V.3  V.4
1    x    y    Z    0
1    x    y    Z    0
1    x    y    Z    0
1    x    y    Z    1
2    x    y    Z    0 
2    x    y    Z    1
3    x    y    Z    0
3    x    y    Z    1
```

The dataset needs to look like this

```
ID V.1a V.2a V.3a V.1b V.2b V.3b V.1c V.2c V.3c V.1d V.2d V.3d V.4
1  x    y    z    x    y    z    x    y    z    x    y    z    4
2  x    y    z    x    y    z    na   na   na   na   na   na   2 
3  x    y    z    x    y    z    na   na   na   na   na   na   2
```

Problem- The number of rows per unique id varies

That seems to be my biggest issue. This has led to having an uneven number of columns and making my usual way to aggregate not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
out <- dcast(dat, ID ~ rowid(ID), value.var = c("V.1", "V.2", "V.3"))[
  dat[, .('V.4' = length(V.4)), by = ID], on = "ID"
]
out
#   ID V.1_1 V.1_2 V.1_3 V.1_4 V.2_1 V.2_2 V.2_3 V.2_4 V.3_1 V.3_2 V.3_3 V.3_4 V.4
#1:  1     x     x     x     x     y     y     y     y     Z     Z     Z     Z   4
#2:  2     x     x  <NA>  <NA>     y     y  <NA>  <NA>     Z     Z  <NA>  <NA>   2
#3:  3     x     x  <NA>  <NA>     y     y  <NA>  <NA>     Z     Z  <NA>  <NA>   2
```

We use `dcast` to spread columns `V.1` to `V.3` from long to wide and join the outcome to `dat[, .('V.4' = length(V.4)), by = ID]` which simply aggregates column `V.4`.

Use `setDF(out)` if you want to continue to work with a `data.frame`.

**data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'ID   V.1  V.2  V.3  V.4
1    x    y    Z    0
1    x    y    Z    0
1    x    y    Z    0
1    x    y    Z    1
2    x    y    Z    0 
2    x    y    Z    1
3    x    y    Z    0
3    x    y    Z    1',
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```